# ¿Cómo mantener el valor de una variable de Javascript al actualizar la página?

Tags: javascript

Buenas tengo este codigo, funciona y todo, pero cuando cambio de disponible a ocupado, mantenimiento o cualquier otro y apreto F5 se pierde el valor y queda de nuevo en disponible, me gustaria que se quedara guardado asi actualice o me salga ¿como se puede hacer eso?

```
<input id="Fmbtn" type="button" value=" Disponible " onclick="sig()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function sig(){
  var array = new Array(" Disponible ", " Ocupado ", " Mantenimiento ",);
  for(i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value == array[i]){
      var indice = (i + 1 == array.length) ? 0 : i + 1;
      document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = array[indice];
      break;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con cookies?

Comment: Como dice @AntoniCobos, si no usas backend para recibir esos datos con ajax, lo mejor es que uses cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es guardar el valor en una base de datos, y al momento de actualizar el navegador vuelve a leer todo el documento y ponerlo en su valor predeterminado, pero si lo guardas en una base de datos, siempre te traera el ultimo valor guardado, y habiendo otra forma es que guardes el valor en la bd del navegador con algo asi...

```
<input id="Fmbtn" type="button" value=" Disponible " onclick="sig()" />

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function sig(){

   var array = new Array(" Disponible ", " Ocupado ", " Mantenimiento ",);

  for(i=0; i < array.length; i++){
     if(document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value == array[i]){
       var indice = (i + 1 == array.length) ? 0 : i + 1;
       document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = array[indice];
       localStorage.setItem("estado", array[indice]);
       break;
    }
  }
}


window.onload=function()
{

    if(localStorage.getItem("estado")!=null)
    {
        estado =localStorage.getItem("estado");

        document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = estado;

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Eduardo, la manera en la que resuelvas el problema depende de los objetivos que quieras alcanzar, pues bien podrías hacer uso de **cookies**, sin embargo, si quieres resolverlo de la manera rápida y sin complicaciones, yo te propongo la siguiente solución:
 Puedes utilizar el objeto **Storage** , el mismo que te permitirá guardar de manera momentánea datos en tu navegador, en consecuencia, aunque recargues el navegador con **F5** los datos no se eliminarán. Tienes dos opciones:

**localStorage:** Los datos se quedarán guardados en el navegador aun, cuando lo cierres y vuelvas a abrirlo.

**sessionStorage:** Los datos se mantendrán mientras el navegador esté abierto.

Su uso es muy simple:

**sessionStorage.setItem('id', 'valor');**

Como imaginarás, **id** es el identificador que te permitrá acceder al **valor** que hayas guardado( **sessionStorage.getItem('id')** ).

Ahora que ya tienes este poder en tus manos, la solución a tu problema es mucho mas simple de lo que crees:

En tu codigo **javascript** puedes hacer que tu button asigne automáticamente el valor que este guardado en el localStorag:

```
  var array = new Array(" Disponible ", " Ocupado ", " Mantenimiento ");

      window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('Fmbtn').value = array[localStorage.getItem("id")?localStorage.getItem("id"):0];
    };
```

*Recuerda marcar la respuesta que mejor te sirva como válida, para que aportes a otras personas de la comunidad con el mismo problema.*

Aqui hay documentación oficial:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Es un gusto ayudarte. Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias!, en serio